# Reverse for 'product_by_catagory' with arguments '('d', 'r', 'e', 's', 's')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<c_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']

Tags: django

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name='shop'
urlpatterns = [

    path('',views.allproduct,name='allproductcat'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/',views.allproduct,name='product_by_catagory')

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from . models import catagory,product

# Create your views here.
def allproduct(request,c_slug=None):
    c_page=None
    products=None
    if c_slug!=None:
        c_page=get_object_or_404(catagory,slug=c_slug)
        products=product.objects.all().filter(catagory=c_page,available=True)
    else:
        products=product.objects.all().filter(available=True)
    return render(request,'catagory.html',{'catagory':c_page,'products':products})
```

catagory.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block metadiscription %}
{% if catagory %}
{{catagory.discription}}
{% else %}
welcome
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}
{% if catagory %}
{{catagory.name}}--ABC store
{% else %}
see our new collection
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% if catagory %}
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'shop:allproduct' %}">OUR PRODUCT COLLECTION</a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
<div>
    {% if catagory %}
    <img src="{{catagory.img.url}}" alt="{{catagory.name}}">
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <h1>
        {{catagory.name}}
    </h1>
    <p>
        {{catagory.discription}}
    </p>

</div>
{% else %}
<div>
    <img src="{% static 'img/banner.png' %}">
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <h1>OUR PRODUCT COLLECTION</h1>
    <p>INDIA IS MY COUNTRY I LOVE MY COUNTRY</p>
</div>
{% endif %}

<div>
    <div>
        {% for product in products %}
        <div>
            <div>
                <a href="" ><img src="{{product.img.url}}"></a>
                <div>
                    <h4>{{product.name}}</h4>
                    <p>{{product.price}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

navbar.html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'shop:allproductcat' %}">ALL PRODUCTS</a></li>
        {% for cat in links %}
        <li><a href="{{cat.get_url}}"></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        <li>YOUR CART</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

context_processors.py

```
from . models import catagory

def menu_link(request):
    link=catagory.objects.all()
    return dict(links=link)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.urls import reverse


class catagory(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique=True)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='catagory',blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering=('name',)
        verbose_name='catagory'
        verbose_name_plural='catagories'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_by_catagory',args=self.slug)
```

i am getting a error that reverse for slug is not found,i cant open my website ,please solve my issue.   Reverse for 'product_by_catagory' with arguments '('d', 'r', 'e', 's', 's')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<c_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/$'].i am not able to run my code,please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you share the `get_url` of the model where the `cat` object belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

You pass items in args as an iterable of objects, even if there is only one parameter. You thus should not implement this as:

```
reverse('shop:product_by_catagory', args=self.slug)
```

but as:

```
reverse('shop:product_by_catagory', args=(self.slug,))
```

here we thus wrap the item in a singleton tuple, such that it only contains *one* item: the `slug` of the `Category` object.

---

> **Note**: Usually Django models implement a [**`.get_absolute_url()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url)
> to determine a canonical URL for that model, not <s>`get_url`</s>. The advantage of
> working with `get_absolute_url` that you can for example pass this to the
> [**`redirect(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> and then it will automatically return a HTTP redirect response with the URL
> generated with the `.get_absolute_url()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`return reverse('eCommerceApp:products_by_category', args=[self.slug])`

Change `args=[self.slug])` to be in square brackets.